# How to render field HTML from tpl file

Tags: entities

I am trying to create a custom field widget and change the HTML of the field through a .tpl file or a theme function. The idea is my field will store some integer value (it will be updated by another form) and show the value in the from of a progresbar. My question is how can I change the HTML of the field. Same question is asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135113/how-to-theme-form-elements-in-a-custom-field-widget) also. Please help if anyone have any clue.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I got the answer how to do this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {

return array(
'my_field' => array(
  'render element' => 'element',
  //  'template' => 'field--field-progress',
  //  'variables' => array('element' => NULL, 'field' => NULL),
   ),
  );
 }
```

Than render the field as below_

```
function theme_progressbar_field($vars){  
  $element = $vars['element'];
  $output = '';
  $output .= '<div class="link-field-subrow12 clearfix">';
  $output .=' <a href="#">';
  $output .='<div class="clearfix  progress-percentage">';
  $output .='<span class="pull-right">'.$element['myfield']['#value'].'%     </span>';
  $output .='</div>';
  $output .='<div class="progress ui-progressbar">';
  $output .='<div class="progress-bar" style="width:'.$element['myfield']   ['#value'].'%"></div>';
  $output .='</div>';
  $output .='</a>' ;
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```